# Empy array values are created when adding to array

Tags: javascript

I have the below code:

```
var changes = new Array();

$(".item_prices").on("blur", function(){
    var item_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var item_price = $(this).html();
    changes[item_id] = item_price;
});
```

Every time a new value is entered, I want to save the item's ID as the key and its price as the value.  If I save items with IDs 4 and 6 and prices 1.99 and 2.99, respectively, I get the following array:

> {,,,,1.99,,2.99}

How do I add to the array without incurring empty values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `object`, not `Array`:

```
var changes = {};
```

The rest is the same.

Key-value should always be saved in an object.

---

Since you're using jQuery, here is another answer to an unasked question,
Use native javascript functions when it's possible and simple, specially when it's even simpler:

```
var item_id = $(this).attr("id");
var item_price = $(this).html();
```

Can and should be:

```
var item_id = this.id
var item_price = this.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want an array, a simple object will form a collection of key value pairs for you:

```
var changes = {};
```

If / when the time comes to enumerate these changes:

```
for (var name in changes) {
  if (changes.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    var value = changes[name];
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array`s are a special case of objects, whose elements have *consecutive* integer keys. You don't have consecutive keys, so `Array` is "filling the gaps" for you.

Use a barebones `Object` instead:

```
var changes = {};
```

Comment: +1, I have no idea why would someone downvote this answer, I really hope it's not related to serial downvotes, as I got 4 unexplained ones.